# Youtube in Webkit/Python/GTK app

Tags: python, webkit, youtube, gtk, python-2.7

I'm trying to do a python(2.7)/GTK+ app, and I have a window, containing a WebKit WebView.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit

class MainWindow:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("youtubeWindow.ui")
        self.main_window = self.builder.get_object("main_window")
        self.scrl_window = self.builder.get_object("scrl_window")
        self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
        self.scrl_window.add(self.webview)
        self.webview.show()  
        self.webview.open("http://youtu.be/o-akcEzQ6Y8")  
        self.main_window.show_all()      
        Gtk.main()     


tube_window = MainWindow()
```

When I run my app I get the folowing error:

> ERROR: Invalid browser function table. Some functionality may be
>   restricted. java version "1.6.0_24" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>   VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
>   ** Message: console message: undefined @0: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

The page loads, but I can't play my video :( (The video box is all black and doesn't have any play button, nothing)

The UI is made in Glade and the XML file generated by Glade, youtubeWindow.ui is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="type_hint">menu</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrl_window">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: accessing the youtube video link from your code it says: "An error occurred during validation. Sorry about that."

Comment: I'm staggered why your error message names OpenJDK as source. Which Python implementation are you using? Cpython / Jython?

Comment: CPython 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04. I think the Java error has something to do with google's youtube player and maybe I have to import some extra stuff to enable WebKit support for Java.
Youtube works on my system in Opera, Firefox and Chrome, so i must be missing something in my code. Maybe something that enables Java in WebKit

Comment: That sounds even more weird. There's no Java on Youtube nowadays. If you supplied your `youtubeWindow.ui` (or minimalist equivalent) I could try it out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. I used

```
import gtk 
import webkit
```

instead of:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit
```

Comment: Don't do this. You're now loading GTK 2 instead of GTK 3, which will cause you headaches down the road, as GTK 2 will become unsupported and unmaintained.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution to your problem. The error message from OpenJDK is irrevelant, it comes from the Java browser plugin and has no effect on what you're trying to do.

Far more important, you make a simple mistake. You simply don't show your window! Add a

```
self.main_window.show_all()
```

before the call to `Gtk.main()` and your window is shown, Youtube video playback starts and everything works properly.

Comment: Ya, thanks, sorry about that.
The code i posted was a simplified version of my app's code, witch apparently i wrote wrong, thanks for the tip, I'll edit my post. 
But i still get the same java error when loading the youtube page

Comment: In my case, everything works fine. I guess you just have to live with some error output rooted somewhere in webkit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is an old question now, but both answers are incorrect.

The code submitted in the question actually runs and displays the video fine. It shows a very small window so you will have to maximize it to see it.